# How to calculate Municipality fee, Service charge, and VAT for restaurants in Dubai

Tags: vat, uae

Restaurants in Dubai charge Municipality fee, Service charge, and VAT.
Let's say all Prices are inclusive/exclusive of 10% service charge, 7% Municipality fee and 5% VAT.

How can I calculate this? Also, if there are other fees (such as tourism fee), how those are calculated?

I tried to calculate it, but I'm not getting the correct amounts.

Amount / ((100 + SC + MF + VAT)/100)
1531 / ((100 + 10 + 7 + 5)/100) = 1254.92

((1531 - 1254.92) / 100) * 10 * (100/22) = 125.49
((1531 - 1254.92) / 100) *  7 * (100/22) = 87.84
((1531 - 1254.92) / 100) *  5 * (100/22) = 62.75

<sup>[Restaurant 01]</sup>
[image: Photo - Sample 01]

<sup>[Restaurant 02]</sup>
[image: Photo - Sample 02]

<sup>[Restaurant 03]</sup>
[image: Photo - Sample 03]

I posted [this question in Travel StackExchange](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/173914/128631) forum, but they suggested I should post here.

Comment: These receipts do not follow the same rules. Could they be from different locations in UAE? #1 has 3.5% municipality fee, #2 and #3 have 7%. UAE is actually several different countries, it may be that the rules between them are different.

Comment: @littleadv, these are three bills from three different restaurants. I do have photos of bills, but I do not know where they were taken in UAE.

Comment: May I ask why it matters?